# Why is Durva grass offered to Lord Ganesha?

Tags: rituals, ganesha, puja

Why is the [Durva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynodon_dactylon) (or scutch grass) offered to Lord Ganesha? What is the reason behind it? Does this grass have any ayurvedic properties? Why is it considered sacred?

[image: Scutch Grass]